# Constructing a vector from range defined by pointers of a smaller type

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

In the following code, a `vector<int>` is constructed from an array of `int8_t`. It happens to work, but is it safe?

```
int8_t *arr;
int arr_size;
... // Filling the array somehow
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + arr_size); // Is this safe even though we use int8_t* to construct a vector of int?
```

The documentation at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) says:

> This constructor has the same effect as `vector(static_cast<size_type>(first), static_cast<value_type>(last), a)` if `InputIt` is an integral type.    (until C++11)
>
> This overload only participates in overload resolution if `InputIt` satisfies `InputIterator`, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2).   (since C++11)

This explanation does not give me a clue about my question. In fact, it confuses me further, since the template arguments for static casts seem to be very wrong...

Comment: The text you quoted addresses a specific niche case that you don't hit. Your code is fine (as is the documentation): you construct a vector from the given range.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do I understand correctly that no cast from `int8_t*` to `int*` is happening?

Comment: Correct. You don't end up with the overload that you've quoted. Your `int8_t*` is not an integral type. (It's a pointer.)

Comment: Should be fine. It knows where the start of the array is and the end of the array (given by the position right after the end). I believe they have an example of this at cplusplus.com.

Comment: Your quoted segment is surely irrelevant, or misquoted, since `size_type` is an integer while `first` in your case is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector constructor you are using is implemented with something similar to the [copy algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = *first++;
     }
    return d_first;
}
```

If both types are the same size, the compiler may further optimize and use `memcpy()`. This optimization happens at a lower level, though, and that's probably what makes you think that it could fail.

The two things required are the length of the input and output containers need to match (done automatically in your case) and the `*d_first++ = *first++;` needs to compile. So if your types are not the same you may need to declare an assignment operator.

Comment: This is a useful analogy, but be careful with it: the question’s operation involves _constructing_ objects, not _assigning_ them.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah, yes. Copy constructors generally work the same way as the copy operators unless `this == &rhs` in which case the copy operation becomes a "do nothing".

Comment: You’re still talking about copy _assignment_: how can `this==&rhs` if `this` points to a _new_ object and `rhs` is an existing object?

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah, indeed... he's not using the copy constructor. I rephrased my first sentence.

Comment: This reply directly addresses the line of thinking that led to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s safe.  All the standard containers can be constructed from any iterator pair where the iterator value type can be (implicitly) converted to the container value type.  The same applies to functions like `insert` or `assign`.